# How to check if a uicontextmenu is visible or active

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

**What I have:**

In a Matlab-GUI I have a uicontextmenu connected to a plot (=axes). If I "activate" this via a mouse-click (right-button), I can use the usual "Callback" to do something, like highlighting the plot. If the user then selects one of the uimenu-elements of the menu, I can use the Callback of this uimenu-element and reset the highlighting.
But there is a problem, if the user does not select an element. The context-menu disappears and I cannot find a way to find out, if this happens. In my example, the highlighted plot stays highlighted.

**What I tried so far:**

Besides reading the docs, I appended listeners to the properties to some of the uimenu-elements, e.g.:

```
addlistener(mymenu_element, 'Visible', 'PostSet', @mytest);
```

but this property, as well as others, seems not to be changed or touched at any time - what suprises me a bit :o

**So the question is:**

Is there a way to execute a function after a uicontextmenu is executed (or however you call it, when a context-menu "disappears")? In other words: if the user does not select an element of a context-menu, how can this be identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cant listen to these items (I've run a few tests and come to the same conclusion) you can work around this by creating and managing your uicontextmenu in a different way:

```
function yourFunction
  % create a figure
  hFig = figure;
  % add a listener to the mouse being pressed
  addlistener ( hFig, 'WindowMousePress', @(a,b)mouseDown(hFig) );
end
function mouseDown(hFig)
  % react depening on the mouse selection type:
  switch hFig.SelectionType
    case 'alt' % right click
      % create a uicontext menu and store in figure data
      hFig.UserData.uic = uicontextmenu ( 'parent', hFig );
      % create the menu items for the uicontextmenu
      uimenu ( 'parent', hFig.UserData.uic, 'Label', 'do this', 'Callback', @(a,b)DoThis(hFig) )
      % assign to the figure
      hFig.UIContextMenu = hFig.UserData.uic;
      % turn visible on and set position
      hFig.UserData.uic.Visible = 'on';
      hFig.UserData.uic.Position = hFig.CurrentPoint;
      % uicontext menu will appear as desired
      % the next mouse action is then to either select an item or
      %  we will capture it below
    otherwise
      % if the uic is stored in the userdata we need to run the clean up 
      %  code since the user has not clicked on one of the items
      if isfield ( hFig.UserData, 'uic' )
        DoThis(hFig);
      end
  end
end
function DoThis(hFig)
  % Your code
  disp ( 'your code' );
  % Clean up
  CleanUp(hFig);
end
function CleanUp(hFig)
  % delete the uicontextmenu and remove the reference to it
  delete(hFig.UserData.uic)
  hFig.UserData = rmfield ( hFig.UserData, 'uic' );
end
```

Comment: This indeed is a very nice and clever workaround! Thanks a lot! However, as my GUI is really complex and performance is critical, I would not like to put a listener on the whole figure all the time. If I put a listener on the axes instead and a listener on the figure at the time the associated callback is triggered, I think this could work out. Within the cleanup, the listener on the figure could then be removed.